# How to animate 2 views from a single point to their final places on appear

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I'm trying to animate the two squares `square` below from a common center point to their final position when they appear, and back - when they are removed.

Here's what I tried, but the result it that they don't start from an overlapping position - rather, they start close to to each in the center:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var matched = true
   @State var show = false
   @Namespace var ns
    
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         HStack {
            Spacer()
            if show {
               square
                  .matchedGeometryEffect(id: matched ? "match" : "", 
                                         in: ns, anchor: .center, isSource: false)
                  .animation(.easeIn)
                  .transition(.move(edge: .trailing ))
                  .onAppear { withAnimation { matched = false } }                        
                  .onDisappear { withAnimation { matched = true } }
            }
            Spacer()
               .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "match", in: ns, anchor: .center, isSource: true)   
            if show {
               square
                  .matchedGeometryEffect(id: matched ? "match" : ""
                                         in: ns, anchor: .center, isSource: false)
                  .animation(.easeIn)
                  .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
            }
            Spacer()
         }
         Button("show") { withAnimation { show.toggle() } }
      }
   }
}
```

The square `square` is simply defined as:

```
var square: some View {
   Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue)
      .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
}
```

---

What sort of worked was to attach `matchedGeometryEffect` to an overlay within `Spacer`, and also to explicitly specify `properties: .position` in all of the them.

Still, it only works when they appear, but not when disappearing; there's still a gap there.

```
Spacer().overlay(
   Color.clear
     .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "match", in: ns, properties: .position, anchor: .center, isSource: true)
   )
```

Is this the right general approach to achieve this effect, and if so, how can I make it work? Or have I overcomplicated it?

Comment: suggestion: until you get the swiftUI answer,
maybe try this on UIKit and wrap it ?

Comment: Interesting use of Spacer. But the middle one might be getting in the way, as it's squeezed out by the rectangles coming together to be removed. Try setting it's frame explicitly and keeping it below: Spacer().frame(width: 40).zIndex(-1)

Comment: @CenkBilgen, the Spacer-Square-Spacer-Square-Spacer structure is what I would like the final layout to be, so I can't set a specific Spacer width - it would break the desired layout. Trying to figure out how to make animate from a central, give that layout

Comment: It would make the flexible spacing fixed. Here's another attempt - answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with geometry matching another clear square with the same dimension and simplified a bit. There's an intrinsic opacity transition that you might want to remove and replace with some color blend mode.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  //@State var matched = true
  @State private var show = false
  @Namespace private var ns
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      
      HStack {
        Spacer()
        if show {
          Square(color: .blue)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 1, in: ns, isSource: false)
        }
        Spacer()
          .background(Square(color: .clear)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: show ? 0 : 1, in: ns, isSource: true))
        if show {
          Square(color: .red)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 1, in: ns, isSource: false)
        }
        Spacer()
      }
       
      Button("show") { withAnimation { show.toggle() } }
    }
  }
  
  struct Square: View {
    let color: Color
    var width: CGFloat = 40
    var body: some View {
      Rectangle().foregroundColor(color).frame(width: width, height: width)
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Interesting.. so this doesn't use transition at all. And it changes the matchedGeometryEffect id of the central one vs what I did. Cool, thanks!